# Spark functions vs UDF performance?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Spark now offers predefined functions that can be used in dataframes, and it seems they are highly optimized. My original question was going to be on which is faster, but I did some testing myself and found the spark functions to be about 10 times faster at least in one instance. Does anyone know why this is so, and when would a udf be faster (only for instances that an identical spark function exists)?

Here is my testing code (ran on Databricks community ed):

```py
# UDF vs Spark function
from faker import Factory
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, concat
fake = Factory.create()
fake.seed(4321)

# Each entry consists of last_name, first_name, ssn, job, and age (at least 1)
from pyspark.sql import Row
def fake_entry():
  name = fake.name().split()
  return (name[1], name[0], fake.ssn(), fake.job(), abs(2016 - fake.date_time().year) + 1)

# Create a helper function to call a function repeatedly
def repeat(times, func, *args, **kwargs):
    for _ in xrange(times):
        yield func(*args, **kwargs)
data = list(repeat(500000, fake_entry))
print len(data)
data[0]

dataDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ('last_name', 'first_name', 'ssn', 'occupation', 'age'))
dataDF.cache()
```

UDF function:

```py
concat_s = udf(lambda s: s+ 's')
udfData = dataDF.select(concat_s(dataDF.first_name).alias('name'))
udfData.count()
```

Spark Function:

```py
spfData = dataDF.select(concat(dataDF.first_name, lit('s')).alias('name'))
spfData.count()
```

Ran both multiple times, the udf usually took about 1.1 - 1.4 s, and the Spark `concat` function always took under 0.15 s.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

> when would a udf be faster

If you ask about Python UDF the answer is probably never*. Since SQL functions are relatively simple and are not designed for complex tasks it is pretty much impossible compensate the cost of repeated serialization, deserialization and data movement between Python interpreter and JVM.

> Does anyone know why this is so

The main reasons are already enumerated above and can be reduced to a simple fact that Spark `DataFrame` is natively a JVM structure and standard access methods are implemented by simple calls to Java API. UDF from the other hand are implemented in Python and require moving data back and forth.

While PySpark in general requires data movements between JVM and Python, in case of low level RDD API it typically doesn't require expensive serde activity. Spark SQL adds additional cost of serialization and serialization as well cost of moving data from and to unsafe representation on JVM. The later one is specific to all UDFs (Python, Scala and Java) but the former one is specific to non-native languages.

Unlike UDFs, Spark SQL functions operate directly on JVM and typically are well integrated with both Catalyst and Tungsten. It means these can be optimized in the execution plan and most of the time can benefit from codgen and other Tungsten optimizations. Moreover these can operate on data in its "native" representation.

So in a sense the problem here is that Python UDF has to bring data to the code while SQL expressions go the other way around.

---

* According to [rough estimates](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/DISCUSS-PySpark-Window-UDF-td23989.html) PySpark window UDF can beat Scala window function.

Comment: Fantastic answer, just what I was looking for. I suspected it was due to data shuffling between Python-Java, just wasn't sure. I appreciate the additional information that these may also benefit from Catalyst and Tungsten so it will be much more important for me to implement them as much as I can in my code and minimize UDFs. A bit off topic, but would you happen to know if numpy capabilities are coming to Spark Dataframes anytime soon? This has kept one of my projects largely on RDDs.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean by "numpy capabilities".

Comment: You can't add a numpy array as a row element. Currently Spark Rows support different data types such as StringType, BoolType, FloatType, but you can't save a numpy array in there.

Comment: If you mean functional numpy object - the safe bet is never. If you mean column type that can be used to store and retrieve then VectorUDT is pretty much this

Comment: "pretty much impossible compensate the cost of repeated serialization, deserialization". These days there is PyArrow that solve this issue.

Comment: @MarcusLind Arrow doesn't solve the problem - it only reduces the symptoms. The real solution would be to have stable (public) binary representation with zero-copy access - something that is technically possible, but not on the roadmap.

Comment: @10465355saysReinstateMonica The point of Arrow is to circumvent the serialization/deserialization process. So in want way does it "only reduce the symptoms". Are you saying that it still have to serialize/deserialize the dataframe when using pandas udf?

Comment: @MarcusLind That's correct. If I recall correctly PysSpark UDFs (and Spark Arrow integration in general) uses Arrow streams, which in turn serialize data using Arrow specific binary formats and all communication still happens over sockets. What you describes matches Arrow's memory interface (for example `pyarrow.py_buffer`), which as far as I am aware, is not used in (Py)Spark. If you think I am wrong, I'd be happy to discuss this further.

Answer (score 60):

After years, when I have a more spark knowledge and had second look on the question, just realized what @alfredox really want to ask. So I revised again, and divide the answer into two parts:

---

To answer Why native DF function (native Spark-SQL function) is faster:

Basically, why native Spark function is ALWAYS faster than Spark UDF, regardless your UDF is implemented in Python or Scala.

Firstly, we need to understand what [Tungsten](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-tungsten.html#whole-stage-code-generation), which is [firstly introduced in Spark 1.4](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html).

It is a backend and what it focus on:

> 1. Off-Heap Memory Management using binary in-memory data representation aka Tungsten row format and managing memory explicitly,
> 2. Cache Locality which is about cache-aware computations with cache-aware   layout for high cache hit rates,
> 3. Whole-Stage Code Generation (aka CodeGen).

*One of the biggest Spark performance killer is GC. The GC would pause the every threads in JVM until the GC finished. This is exactly why Off-Heap Memory Management being introduced.*

When executing Spark-SQL native functions, the data will stays in tungsten backend. However, in Spark UDF scenario, the data will be moved out from tungsten into JVM (Scala scenario) or JVM and Python Process (Python) to do the actual process, and then move back into tungsten. As a result of that:

1. Inevitably, there would be a overhead / penalty on :

   1. Deserialize the input from tungsten.
   2. Serialize the output back into tungsten.
2. Even using Scala, the first-class citizen in Spark, it will increase the memory footprint within JVM, and which may likely involve more **GC** within JVM. 
   **This issue exactly what tungsten "Off-Heap Memory Management" feature try to address**.

---

To answer if Python would necessarily slower than Scala:

Since 30th October, 2017, Spark just introduced vectorized udfs for pyspark.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

The reason that Python UDF is slow, is probably the PySpark UDF is not implemented in a most optimized way:

According to the paragraph from the link.

> Spark added a Python API in version 0.7, with support for user-defined functions. These user-defined functions operate **one-row-at-a-time**, and thus suffer from high serialization and invocation overhead.

However the newly vectorized udfs seem to be improving the performance a lot:

> ranging from 3x to over 100x.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the higher-level standard Column-based functions with Dataset operators whenever possible before reverting to using your own custom UDF functions since UDFs are a **BlackBox** for Spark and so it does **not even try** to optimize them.

What actually happens behind the screens, is that the Catalyst can’t process and optimize UDFs at all, and it treats them as BlackBox, which results in losing many optimizations like Predicate pushdown, Constant folding and many others.

Comment: Can a map be used instead of sparUDF ? That way can we gain performance with tungsten?

Comment: in case anyone reads this - no, map is often even worse as it's forces serialisation of a whole object, not just the fields used in a udf

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question.

I was interested in how a PySpark native fn vs UDF compares.
The original code snippet smells and is bleeding badly from many deep wounds.
So I fixed it and pimped it a little bit so I can run it on my system.

> Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, 6.0.9-060009-generic
> Python 3.10.6
> Pyspark 3.3.2

On my box, the result is about:

```
------- [with_spark_udf x10] Execution time: 4.780205 seconds
------- [with_spark_func x10] Execution time: 1.154016 seconds
```

```py
import timeit

import faker
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit, udf

"""
Spark native function vs Spark UDF
"""


def speed_test(number_of_execution_: int):
    def real_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            execution_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: func(*args, **kwargs), number=number_of_execution_)
            print(f"------- [{func.__name__} x{number_of_execution_}] Execution time: {execution_time:.6f} seconds")
            return
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator


def fake_entry():
    """
    Each entry consists of last_name, first_name, ssn, job, and age (at least 1)
    """
    name = fake.name().split()
    return name[1], name[0], fake.ssn(), fake.job(), abs(2016 - fake.date_time().year) + 1


def _repeat(times: int, func: callable, *args, **kwargs) -> any:
    """
    A helper function to call a function repeatedly
    """
    for _ in range(times):
        yield func(*args, **kwargs)


def concat_s(s: str) -> str:
    return s + 's'


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark_native_fn_vs_udf').getOrCreate()

fake = faker.Factory.create()
fake.seed(4321)

data = list(_repeat(50000, fake_entry))
print(f"len(data): {len(data)}")
print(f"data[0]: \n{data[0]}")

data_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=['last_name', 'first_name', 'ssn', 'occupation', 'age'])
data_df.cache()

# the UDF
udf_concat_s = udf(concat_s)

CYCLES = 10


@speed_test(CYCLES)
def with_spark_udf(): 
    udf_data = data_df.select(udf_concat_s(data_df.first_name).alias('name')).collect()


@speed_test(CYCLES)
def with_spark_func(): 
    spf_data = data_df.select(concat(data_df.first_name, lit('s')).alias('name')).collect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with_spark_udf()
    with_spark_func()
```

I hope this is helpful in some weird way.