# How to group by multiple columns and collect in list in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my problem:
I've got this RDD:

```python
a = [[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a2',u'a3'],[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a5',u'a6'],[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a8',u'a9']]

rdd= sc.parallelize (a)
```

Then I try :

```python
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2], list(x[3:])))

.toDF(["col1","col2","col3","col4"])

.groupBy("col1","col2","col3")

.agg(collect_list("col4")).show
```

Finally I should find this:

> ```python
> [col1,col2,col3,col4]=[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',[[u'a2',u'a3'][u'a5',u'a6'][u'a8',u'a9']]]
> ```

But the problem is that I can't collect a list.

If anyone can help me I will appreciate it

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't collect a list" ?

Comment: That function collect_list can't receive a list.. I try to collect a list of lists

Comment: which version of spark are you using ?

Comment: Spark version 1.6.2

Comment: Can you switch to spark 2+ ? Spark 1.6 uses hive UDAF to perform collect_list which has been re-implemented in spark 2+ to accept lists of list

Comment: I can't, in this platform there are a lot of automatic processes and if we upgrade, we should migrate every one of them.. :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution, it is not the best way but I can continue working...

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def example(lista):
    d = [[] for x in range(len(lista))]
    for index, elem in enumerate(lista):
      d[index] = elem.split("@")
    return d
example_udf = udf(example, LongType())

a = [[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a2',u'a3'],[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a5',u'a6'],[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a8',u'a9']]

rdd= sc.parallelize (a)

df = rdd.toDF(["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"])

df2=df.withColumn('col6', concat(col('col4'),lit('@'),col('col5'))).drop(col("col4")).drop(col("col5")).groupBy([col("col1"),col("col2"),col("col3")]).agg(collect_set(col("col6")).alias("col6"))

df2.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2],example(x[3]))).collect()
```

And it gives:

```python
[(u'PNR1', u'TKT1', u'TEST', [[u'a2', u'a3'], [u'a5', u'a6'], [u'a8', u'a9']])]
```

Hope this solution can help to someone else.

Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

This might do your job (or give you some ideas to proceed further)...

One idea is to convert your `col4` to a primitive data type, i.e. a string:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
import pandas as pd

a = [[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a2',u'a3'],[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a5',u'a6'],[u'PNR1',u'TKT1',u'TEST',u'a8',u'a9']]
rdd = sc.parallelize(a)

df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2], '(' + ' '.join(str(e) for e in x[3:]) + ')')).toDF(["col1","col2","col3","col4"])

df.groupBy("col1","col2","col3").agg(collect_list("col4")).toPandas().values.tolist()[0]
#[u'PNR1', u'TKT1', u'TEST', [u'(a2 a3)', u'(a5 a6)', u'(a8 a9)']]
```

**UPDATE** (after your own answer):

I really thought the point I had reached above was enough to further adapt it according to your needs, plus that I didn't have time at the moment to do it myself; so, here it is (after modifying my `df` definition to get rid of the parentheses, it is just a matter of a single list comprehension):

```python
df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2], ' '.join(str(e) for e in x[3:]))).toDF(["col1","col2","col3","col4"])

# temp list:
ff = df.groupBy("col1","col2","col3").agg(collect_list("col4")).toPandas().values.tolist()[0]
ff
# [u'PNR1', u'TKT1', u'TEST', [u'a2 a3', u'a5 a6', u'a8 a9']]

# final list of lists:
ll = ff[:-1] + [[x.split(' ') for x in ff[-1]]]
ll
```

which gives your initially requested result:

```python
[u'PNR1', u'TKT1', u'TEST', [[u'a2', u'a3'], [u'a5', u'a6'], [u'a8', u'a9']]]  # requested output
```

This approach has certain **advantages** compared with the one provided in your own answer:

- It avoids Pyspark UDFs, which are [known to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)
- All the processing is done in the final (and hopefully much smaller) aggregated data, instead of adding and removing columns and performing map functions and UDFs in the initial (presumably much bigger) data

Comment: Actually I need a list of lists in col4, in your answer I've in string type (a2 a3) for example, and I need [[a2,a3],[a5,a6],[a8,a9]]

Comment: @CarlosLopezSobrino isn't the updated answer exactly what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot update to 2.x your only option is RDD API. Replace you current code with:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1], x[2]), list(x[3:]))).groupByKey().toDF()
```