# combine text from multiple rows in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I created a PySpark dataframe using the following code

```python
testlist = [
             {"category":"A","name":"A1"}, 
             {"category":"A","name":"A2"}, 
             {"category":"B","name":"B1"},
             {"category":"B","name":"B2"}
]

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(testlist)
```

Result:

```python
category    name
A           A1
A           A2
B           B1
B           B2
```

I want to make it appear as follows:

```python
category    name
A           A1, A2
B           B1, B2
```

I tried the following code which does not work

```python
spark_df.groupby('category').agg('name', lambda x:x + ', ')
```

Can anyone help identify what I am doing wrong and the best way to make this happen ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One option is to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) as the aggregate function.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
grouped_df = spark_df.groupby('category').agg(collect_list('name').alias("name"))
```

This will collect the values for `name` into a list and the resultant output will look like:

```python
grouped_df.show()
#+---------+---------+
#|category |name     |
#+---------+---------+
#|A        |[A1, A2] |
#|B        |[B1, B2] |
#+---------+---------+
```

**Update** 2019-06-10: 
If you wanted your output as a concatenated string, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) to concatenate the values of the collected list, which will be [better than using a `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws

grouped_df.withColumn("name", concat_ws(", ", "name")).show()
#+---------+-------+
#|category |name   |
#+---------+-------+
#|A        |A1, A2 |
#|B        |B1, B2 |
#+---------+-------+
```

---

**Original Answer**: If you wanted your output as a concatenated string, you'd <strike>have to</strike> *can* use a `udf`. For example, you can first do the `groupBy()` as above and the apply a `udf` to join the collected list:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
concat_list = udf(lambda lst: ", ".join(lst), StringType())

grouped_df.withColumn("name", concat_list("name")).show()
#+---------+-------+
#|category |name   |
#+---------+-------+
#|A        |A1, A2 |
#|B        |B1, B2 |
#+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Hi pault, thanks for your help. I am wondering how you got the answer. I tried exactly the same and I get the error 'NoneType does not have attribute withColumn'. Please let me know if I should correct something. Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you didn't set `grouped_df` equal to that output of `.show()`? That error means the df for which you are calling `withColumn()` is actually `None`

Answer (score 3):

### UNIQUE values

If you want **unique** values then use `collect_set` instead of `collect_list`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set
grouped_df = sdf.groupby('category').agg(collect_set('name').alias("unique_name"))
sdf.show(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is this

```
>>> df.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+','+y).toDF().show()
+---+-----+
| _1|   _2|
+---+-----+
|  A|A1,A2|
|  B|B1,B2|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Hi Bala, Thanks for your help. I tried your script on my data which has more than instances of each key. It gives me the error:   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: `reduceByKey` works with more than one instance of key. Can you give us sample data having exact pattern you are working with.