# Pyspark converting an array of struct into string

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in Pyspark

```
+----+-------+-----+                                                            
|name|subject|score|
+----+-------+-----+
| Tom|   math|   90|
| Tom|physics|   70|
| Amy|   math|   95|
+----+-------+-----+
```

I used `collect_list` and `struct` function from `pyspark.sql.functions`

```
df.groupBy('name').agg(collect_list(struct('subject', 'score')).alias('score_list'))
```

to get the following dataframe

```
+----+--------------------+
|name|          score_list|
+----+--------------------+
| Tom|[[math, 90], [phy...|
| Amy|        [[math, 95]]|
+----+--------------------+
```

My question is how can I transform the last column `score_list` into string and dump it into a csv file looks like

```
Tom     (math, 90) | (physics, 70)
Amy     (math, 95)
```

Appreciate for any help, thanks.

Update: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788919/concatenating-string-by-rows-in-pyspark) is a similar question but it's not exactly the same because it goes directly from `string` to another `string`. In my case, I want to first transfer `string` to **`collect_list<struct>`** and finally stringify this **`collect_list<struct>`**.

Comment: Use [`concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) - looking for a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenating string by rows in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788919/concatenating-string-by-rows-in-pyspark), or [combine text from multiple rows in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468362/combine-text-from-multiple-rows-in-pyspark), or [Combine multiple rows into a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026590/combine-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row).

Comment: what's the version of your spark?

Comment: @jxc I use spark 2.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duplicates I linked don't exactly answer your question, since you're combining multiple columns. Nevertheless you can modify the solutions to fit your desired output quite easily.

Just replace the `struct` with [`concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws). Also use [`concat`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) to add an opening and closing parentheses to get the output you desire.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, concat_ws, lit

df = df.groupBy('name')\
    .agg(
        concat_ws(
            " | ", 
            collect_list(
                concat(lit("("), concat_ws(", ", 'subject', 'score'), lit(")"))
            )
        ).alias('score_list')
    )
df.show(truncate=False)

#+----+--------------------------+
#|name|score_list                |
#+----+--------------------------+
#|Tom |(math, 90) | (physics, 70)|
#|Amy |(math, 95)                |
#+----+--------------------------+
```

Note that since the comma appears in the `score_list` column, this value will be quoted when you write to `csv` if you use the default arguments.

For example:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("test.csv")
```

Would produce the following output file:

```
Tom,"(math, 90) | (physics, 70)"
Amy,"(math, 95)"
```

Answer (score 7):

Per your Update and comment, for *Spark 2.4.0+*, here is one way to stringify an array of structs with Spark SQL builtin functions: [**transform**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) and [**array_join**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#array_join):

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: integer (nullable = true)

>>> df.show(2,0)
+----+---------------------------+
|name|score_list                 |
+----+---------------------------+
|Tom |[[math, 90], [physics, 70]]|
|Amy |[[math, 95]]               |
+----+---------------------------+

>>> df1.selectExpr(
        "name"
      , """
         array_join(
             transform(score_list, x -> concat('(', x.subject, ', ', x.score, ')'))
           , ' | '
         ) AS score_list
        """
).show(2,0)

+----+--------------------------+
|name|score_list                |
+----+--------------------------+
|Tom |(math, 90) | (physics, 70)|
|Amy |(math, 95)                |
+----+--------------------------+
```

Where:

1. Use **transform()** to convert array of structs into array of strings. for each array element (the struct `x`), we use `concat('(', x.subject, ', ', x.score, ')')` to convert it into a string.
2. Use **array_join()** to join all array elements(StringType) with `|` , this will return the final string