# how could I merge the column that was duplicated in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, merge

I have a dataframe as below:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 _id|           statement|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   1|            ssssssss|
|                   2|            ssssssss|
|                   3|            aaaaaaaa|
|                   4|            aaaaaaaa|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

After using df.dropDuplicates(['statement']), I got this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 _id|           statement|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   1|            ssssssss|
|                   3|            aaaaaaaa|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

But actually, I want to keep the _id value as below:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 _id|           statement|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                1, 2|            ssssssss|
|                3, 4|            aaaaaaaa|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally find my answer in [combine text from multiple rows in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468362/combine-text-from-multiple-rows-in-pyspark)

```
sdf.groupBy('lstatement').agg(F.collect_list('_id').alias("_id")).show()
```