# Pivot and Concatenate columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot

I have this dataframe below, and I need to get basically one row with all the marks fields concatenated with a delimiter like pipe.
So: PACKAGING MARKS 3|PACKAGING MARKS 2|PACKAG.....

And there can be varying amounts of marks records for each mid.

| mid | marksId | id | index | marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | PACKAGING MARKS 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | PACKAGING MARKS 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 0 | PACKAGING MARKS 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | PACKAGING MARKS 23 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 | PACKAGING MARKS 22 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 0 | PACKAGING MARKS 21 |

Thanks

Comment: see `collect_list` function and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49468362/8279585)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want 1 delimited string for each "mid", you can collect all "marks" with `collect_list()` and use `concat_ws()` to create the string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupby('mid').agg(F.concat_ws('|', F.collect_list('marks')).alias('marks_str')).show(truncate=False)
```