# Pyspark string pattern from columns values and regexp expression

Tags: regex, pyspark, pattern-matching, callable-object

Hi I have dataframe with 2 columns :

```
+----------------------------------------+----------+
|                  Text                  | Key_word |
+----------------------------------------+----------+
| First random text tree cheese cat      | tree     |
| Second random text apple pie three     | text     |
| Third random text burger food brain    | brain    |
| Fourth random text nothing thing chips | random   |
+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

I want to generate a 3rd columns with a word appearing before the key_word from the text.

```
+----------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+--+
|                  Text                  | Key_word | word_bef_key_word |  |
+----------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+--+
| First random text tree cheese cat      | tree     | text              |  |
| Second random text apple pie three     | text     | random            |  |
| Third random text burger food brain    | brain    | food              |  |
| Fourth random text nothing thing chips | random   | Fourth            |  |
+----------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+--+
```

I tried this but it's not working

```
df2=df1.withColumn('word_bef_key_word',regexp_extract(df1.Text,('\\w+)'df1.key_word,1))
```

Here is the code to create a example of the dataframe

```
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('First random text tree cheese cat' , 'tree'),
        ('Second random text apple pie three', 'text'),
        ('Third random text burger food brain' , 'brain'),
        ('Fourth random text nothing thing chips', 'random')
    ],
    ('Text', 'Key_word') 
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

You can also [do this without a `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance) by using [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) to pass [column values as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function) to [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df.withColumn(
    'word_bef_key_word', 
    expr(r"regexp_extract(Text, concat('\\w+(?= ', Key_word, ')'), 0)")
)
df.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
#|Text                                  |Key_word|word_bef_key_word|
#+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
#|First random text tree cheese cat     |tree    |text             |
#|Second random text apple pie three    |text    |random           |
#|Third random text burger food brain   |brain   |food             |
#|Fourth random text nothing thing chips|random  |Fourth           |
#+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
```

---

**Original Answer**

One way to do this is by using a `udf` to do the regex:

```python
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def get_previous_word(text, key_word):
    matches = re.findall(r'\w+(?= {kw})'.format(kw=key_word), text)
    return matches[0] if matches else None

get_previous_word_udf = udf(
    lambda text, key_word: get_previous_word(text, key_word),
    StringType()
)

df = df.withColumn('word_bef_key_word', get_previous_word_udf('Text', 'Key_word'))
df.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
#|Text                                  |Key_word|word_bef_key_word|
#+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
#|First random text tree cheese cat     |tree    |text             |
#|Second random text apple pie three    |text    |random           |
#|Third random text burger food brain   |brain   |food             |
#|Fourth random text nothing thing chips|random  |Fourth           |
#+--------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
```

The regex pattern `'\w+(?= {kw})'.format(kw=key_word)` means match a word followed by a space and the `key_word`. If there are multiple matches, we will return the first one. If there are no matches, the function returns `None`.