# Using a column value as a parameter to a spark DataFrame function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following DataFrame:

```python
#+------+---+
#|letter|rpt|
#+------+---+
#|     X|  3|
#|     Y|  1|
#|     Z|  2|
#+------+---+
```

which can be created using the following code:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame([("X", 3),("Y", 1),("Z", 2)], ["letter", "rpt"])
```

Suppose I wanted to repeat each row the number of times specified in the column `rpt`, just like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109018/pyspark-replicate-row-based-on-column-value).

One way would be to replicate my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109986/5858851) to that question using the following `pyspark-sql` query:

```python
query = """
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT *,
                   posexplode(split(repeat(",", rpt), ",")) AS (index, col)
   FROM df) AS a
WHERE index > 0
"""
query = query.replace("\n", " ")  # replace newlines with spaces, avoid EOF error
spark.sql(query).drop("col").sort('letter', 'index').show()
#+------+---+-----+
#|letter|rpt|index|
#+------+---+-----+
#|     X|  3|    1|
#|     X|  3|    2|
#|     X|  3|    3|
#|     Y|  1|    1|
#|     Z|  2|    1|
#|     Z|  2|    2|
#+------+---+-----+
```

This works and produces the correct answer. However, I am unable to replicate this behavior using the DataFrame API functions.

I tried:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.select(
    f.posexplode(f.split(f.repeat(",", f.col("rpt")), ",")).alias("index", "col")
).show()
```

But this results in:

> `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Why am I able to pass the column as an input to `repeat` within the query, but not from the API? Is there a way to replicate this behavior using the spark DataFrame functions?

Comment: `f.expr("""repeat(",", rpt)""")` instead of `f.repeat(",", f.col("rpt"))`?

Comment: @user8371915 `df.select('*', f.expr('posexplode(split(repeat(",", rpt), ","))').alias("index", "col")).where('index > 0').drop("col").sort('letter', 'index').show()` works. Do you know if this is the only way to use a Column as a parameter? Why does it work in the sql syntax?

Comment: @user8371915 please consider posting your suggestion as an answer (and it can be edited it out of my question). I think it would be beneficial to others in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr), which allows you to use columns values as inputs to spark-sql functions.

Based on @user8371915's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function#comment89265333_51140470) I have found that the following works:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.select(
    '*',
    expr('posexplode(split(repeat(",", rpt), ","))').alias("index", "col")
).where('index > 0').drop("col").sort('letter', 'index').show()
#+------+---+-----+
#|letter|rpt|index|
#+------+---+-----+
#|     X|  3|    1|
#|     X|  3|    2|
#|     X|  3|    3|
#|     Y|  1|    1|
#|     Z|  2|    1|
#|     Z|  2|    2|
#+------+---+-----+
```