# get all the dates between two dates in Spark DataFrame

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF in which I have `bookingDt` and `arrivalDt` columns. I need to find all the dates between these two dates.

**Sample code:**

```python
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
            [Row(vyge_id=1000, bookingDt='2018-01-01', arrivalDt='2018-01-05')]).toDF()
diffDaysDF = df.withColumn("diffDays", datediff('arrivalDt', 'bookingDt'))
diffDaysDF.show()
```

**code output:**

```python
+----------+----------+-------+--------+
| arrivalDt| bookingDt|vyge_id|diffDays|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|       4|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+
```

What I tried was finding the number of days between two dates and calculate all the dates using `timedelta` function and `explode` it.

```python
dateList = [str(bookingDt + timedelta(i)) for i in range(diffDays)]
```

**Expected output:**

Basically, I need to build a DF with a record for each date in between `bookingDt` and `arrivalDt`, inclusive.

```python
+----------+----------+-------+----------+
| arrivalDt| bookingDt|vyge_id|txnDt     |
+----------+----------+-------+----------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-01|
+----------+----------+-------+----------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-02|
+----------+----------+-------+----------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-03|
+----------+----------+-------+----------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-04|
+----------+----------+-------+----------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-05|
+----------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As long as you're using Spark version 2.1 or higher, you can exploit the fact that we can use [column values as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function) when using [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr):

- Create a dummy string of repeating commas with a length equal to `diffDays`
- Split this string on `','` to turn it into an array of size `diffDays`
- Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) to explode this array along with its indices
- Finally use [`pyspark.sql.functions.date_add()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_add) to add the index value number of days to the `bookingDt`

Code:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

diffDaysDF.withColumn("repeat", f.expr("split(repeat(',', diffDays), ',')"))\
    .select("*", f.posexplode("repeat").alias("txnDt", "val"))\
    .drop("repeat", "val", "diffDays")\
    .withColumn("txnDt", f.expr("date_add(bookingDt, txnDt)"))\
    .show()
#+----------+----------+-------+----------+
#| arrivalDt| bookingDt|vyge_id|     txnDt|
#+----------+----------+-------+----------+
#|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-01|
#|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-02|
#|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-03|
#|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-04|
#|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-05|
#+----------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want.. but is it possible to improve this. seems quite complex..

Comment: One way may be to create one dataframe of dates to join with like @Volodymyr suggested using this method. Essentially select the min booking date and the max arrival date, compute the difference in days, and create one dataframe with all dates inbetween.

Answer (score 28):

For **Spark 2.4+** [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#sequence) can be used to create an array containg all dates between `bookingDt` and `arrivalDt`. This array can then be exploded.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df \
  .withColumn('bookingDt', F.col('bookingDt').cast('date')) \
  .withColumn('arrivalDt', F.col('arrivalDt').cast('date'))

df.withColumn('txnDt', F.explode(F.expr('sequence(bookingDt, arrivalDt, interval 1 day)')))\
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
|vyge_id| bookingDt| arrivalDt|     txnDt|
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
|   1000|2018-01-01|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|
|   1000|2018-01-01|2018-01-05|2018-01-02|
|   1000|2018-01-01|2018-01-05|2018-01-03|
|   1000|2018-01-01|2018-01-05|2018-01-04|
|   1000|2018-01-01|2018-01-05|2018-01-05|
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 11):

Well, you can do following.

Create a dataframe with dates only:

`dates_df` # with all days between first `bookingDt` and last `arrivalDt`

and then join those df with between condition:

```
df.join(dates_df, 
  on=col('dates_df.dates').between(col('df.bookindDt'), col('dt.arrivalDt'))
.select('df.*', 'dates_df.dates')
```

It might work even faster then solution with `explode`, however you need to figure out what is start and end date for this df. 
*10 years df will have just 3650 records not that many to worry about.*

Answer (score 2):

As @vvg suggested:

```python
# I assume, bookindDt has dates range including arrivalDt, 
# otherwise you have to find intersection of unique dates of bookindDt and arrivalDt

dates_df = df.select('bookindDt').distinct()
dates_df = dates_df.withColumnRenamed('bookindDt', 'day_of_listing')

listing_days_df = df.join(dates_df, on=dates_df.day_of_listing.between(df.bookindDt, df.arrivalDt))
```

**Output:**

```python
+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
| arrivalDt| bookingDt|vyge_id|day_of_listing     |
+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-01         |
+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-02         |
+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-03         |
+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-04         |
+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|2018-01-05|2018-01-01|   1000|2018-01-05         |
+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
```