# How to Loop through dataframe and add array to each row

Tags: pyspark

I need to loop through pyspark dataframe and blast each row in number of active months. My major concern is memory management when I am trying to put the data in hive and time consumed in the process.

I have used collect with `"idx", F.monotonically_increasing_id()`
but this has killed the performance of my code.

Input

```
Empid date_active date_end
1234  2012-01-01  2012-10-27
2345  2012-01-01  2012-12-31
3456  2012-01-01  2012-08-15
```

Output

```
EmpId effective_Month
1234  Jan-12
1234  Feb-12
1234  ....
1234  Oct-12
2345  Jan-12
2345  Feb-12
2345  ....
2345  Dec-12
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
for f in dfMT.collect():
    d = []
    MemberId = f.MemberId
    mth = f.months
    #c = int(mth, 0)
    sd = f.FromDate
    ed = f.ToDate
    lst = [dt.strptime('%2.2d-%2.2d' % (y, m), '%Y-%m').strftime('%b-%y')
           for y in range(sd.year, ed.year+1)
           for m in range(sd.month if y==sd.year else 1, ed.month+1 if y == ed.year else 13)]
    for n in range (mth):
        d.append({"MemberId" : MemberId, "MonthName" : lst[n]})
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

Comment: spark_df = hive_context.createDataFrame(df)    
    spark_df.write.mode('append').format('hive').saveAsTable('test123')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get all the dates between two dates in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745007/get-all-the-dates-between-two-dates-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Are `date_active` and `date_end` always guaranteed to be in the same year?

Comment: Also possible dupe of [Generating monthly timestamps between two dates in pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412643/generating-monthly-timestamps-between-two-dates-in-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating monthly timestamps between two dates in pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412643/generating-monthly-timestamps-between-two-dates-in-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this as below in data frame API

Creating a sample data frame

```
  df = spark.createDataFrame([["123","2012-01-01","2012-10-01"],['234', '2012-01-01', '2012-05-01'],["345","2012-01-01","2012-11-01"]], ("age","date_active", "date_end"))

    +---+-----------+----------+
    |age|date_active|  date_end|
    +---+-----------+----------+
    |123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|
    |234| 2012-01-01|2012-05-01|
    |345| 2012-01-01|2012-11-01|
    +---+-----------+----------+
```

Changing data type from string to timestamp

```
df = df.withColumn('date_active', df['date_active'].cast('timestamp'))\
.withColumn('date_end', df['date_end'].cast('timestamp'))
```

Using below code adding the month column

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn('month_diff', f.months_between('date_end', 'date_active')).withColumn("repeat", f.expr("split(repeat(',', month_diff), ',')"))\
.select("*", f.posexplode("repeat").alias("date", "val")).withColumn("date", f.expr("add_months(date_active, date)"))\
.withColumn('month', f.date_format('date','MMM')).select(['age', 'date_active', 'date_end', 'month']).show()


---+-----------+----------+-----+
|age|date_active|  date_end|month|
+---+-----------+----------+-----+
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Jan|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Feb|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Mar|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Apr|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  May|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Jun|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Jul|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Aug|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Sep|
|123| 2012-01-01|2012-10-01|  Oct|
|234| 2012-01-01|2012-05-01|  Jan|
|234| 2012-01-01|2012-05-01|  Feb|
|234| 2012-01-01|2012-05-01|  Mar|
|234| 2012-01-01|2012-05-01|  Apr|
|234| 2012-01-01|2012-05-01|  May|
|345| 2012-01-01|2012-11-01|  Jan|
|345| 2012-01-01|2012-11-01|  Feb|
|345| 2012-01-01|2012-11-01|  Mar|
|345| 2012-01-01|2012-11-01|  Apr|
|345| 2012-01-01|2012-11-01|  May|
+---+-----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: replace withColumn('month', f.date_format('date','MMM')) with withColumn('month', f.date_format('date','MMM-YY')).

Comment: Thanks Ravi on first hand code ran very well and did the trick. Thanks Vikrant for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I would suggest to try using an udf. I had a similar problem once, but I considered the solution still too complicated.

Instead you could change your perspective on the problem. When you know your `min(date_active)` and `max(date_end)` of all `EmpIds`, you can iterate through all months e.g. `'yyyy-mm-01'` and save it as a dataframe.
Now you (broadcast-)join the resulting dataframe with every single row of your table. At last you only need a simple filter like: `when effective_month between date_active and date_end`.
In the end you should transform `effective_month` into the string format you prefer.

Broadcast Joins are very fast, if the broadcasted table is small, such that runtime shouldn't be a problem here.