# Update values in a column based on values of another data frame's column values in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, intersection, collect

I have two data frames in PySpark: `df1`

```
+---+-----------------+
|id1|           items1|
+---+-----------------+
|  0|     [B, C, D, E]|
|  1|        [E, A, C]|
|  2|     [F, A, E, B]|
|  3|        [E, G, A]|
|  4|  [A, C, E, B, D]|
+---+-----------------+
```

and `df2`:

```
+---+-----------------+
|id2|           items2|
+---+-----------------+
|001|              [B]|
|002|              [A]|
|003|              [C]|
|004|              [E]|
+---+-----------------+
```

I would like to create a new column in `df1` that would update values in 
`items1` column, so that it only keeps values that also appear (in any row of) `items2` in `df2`. The result should look as follows:

```
+---+-----------------+----------------------+
|id1|           items1|        items1_updated|
+---+-----------------+----------------------+
|  0|     [B, C, D, E]|             [B, C, E]|
|  1|        [E, A, C]|             [E, A, C]|
|  2|     [F, A, E, B]|             [A, E, B]|
|  3|        [E, G, A]|                [E, A]|
|  4|  [A, C, E, B, D]|          [A, C, E, B]|
+---+-----------------+----------------------+
```

I would normally use collect() to get a list of all values in `items2` column and then use a udf applied to each row in `items1` to get an intersection. But the data is extremely large (over 10 million rows) and I cannot use collect() to get such list. Is there a way to do this while keeping data in a data frame format? Or some other way without using collect()?

Comment: is datatype of  items1 and items2 columns are arraytype or string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is [`explode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the values in `df2.items2` so that contents of the arrays will be on separate rows:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df2 = df2.select(explode("items2").alias("items2"))
df2.show()
#+------+
#|items2|
#+------+
#|     B|
#|     A|
#|     C|
#|     E|
#+------+
```

(This assumes that the values in `df2.items2` are distinct- if not, you would need to add `df2 = df2.distinct()`.)

**Option 1**: Use `crossJoin`:

Now you can `crossJoin` the new `df2` back to `df1` and keep only the rows where `df1.items1` contains an element in `df2.items2`. We can achieve this using [`pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains) and [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264737/5858851) that allows us to [use a column value as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).

After filtering, group by `id1` and `items1` and aggregate using [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list)

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, collect_list

df1.alias("l").crossJoin(df2.alias("r"))\
    .where(expr("array_contains(l.items1, r.items2)"))\
    .groupBy("l.id1", "l.items1")\
    .agg(collect_list("r.items2").alias("items1_updated"))\
    .show()
#+---+---------------+--------------+
#|id1|         items1|items1_updated|
#+---+---------------+--------------+
#|  1|      [E, A, C]|     [A, C, E]|
#|  0|   [B, C, D, E]|     [B, C, E]|
#|  4|[A, C, E, B, D]|  [B, A, C, E]|
#|  3|      [E, G, A]|        [A, E]|
#|  2|   [F, A, E, B]|     [B, A, E]|
#+---+---------------+--------------+
```

**Option 2**: Explode `df1.items1` and left join:

Another option is to `explode` the contents of `items1` in `df1` and do a left join. After the join, we have to do a similar group by and aggregation as above. This works because `collect_list` will ignore the `null` values introduced by the non-matching rows

```python
df1.withColumn("items1", explode("items1")).alias("l")\
    .join(df2.alias("r"), on=expr("l.items1=r.items2"), how="left")\
    .groupBy("l.id1")\
    .agg(
        collect_list("l.items1").alias("items1"),
        collect_list("r.items2").alias("items1_updated")
    ).show()
#+---+---------------+--------------+
#|id1|         items1|items1_updated|
#+---+---------------+--------------+
#|  0|   [E, B, D, C]|     [E, B, C]|
#|  1|      [E, C, A]|     [E, C, A]|
#|  3|      [E, A, G]|        [E, A]|
#|  2|   [F, E, B, A]|     [E, B, A]|
#|  4|[E, B, D, C, A]|  [E, B, C, A]|
#+---+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. What an elegant solution! It works well locally, I'll test it tomorrow on larger data. But your explanation is very clear and helped me understand why this approach should be used. Do you mind also looking at a related question for me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935724/creating-an-indicator-array-based-on-other-data-frames-column-values-in-pyspark