# Creating an indicator array based on other data frame's column values in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, indicator, collect

I have two data frames: `df1`

```
+---+-----------------+
|id1|           items1|
+---+-----------------+
|  0|     [B, C, D, E]|
|  1|        [E, A, C]|
|  2|     [F, A, E, B]|
|  3|        [E, G, A]|
|  4|  [A, C, E, B, D]|
+---+-----------------+
```

and `df2`:

```
+---+-----------------+
|id2|           items2|
+---+-----------------+
|001|           [A, C]|
|002|              [D]|
|003|        [E, A, B]|
|004|        [B, D, C]|
|005|           [F, B]|
|006|           [G, E]|
+---+-----------------+
```

I would like to create an indicator vector (in a new column `result_array` in `df1`) based on values in `items2`. The vector should be of the same length as number of rows in `df2` (in this example it should have 6 elements). Its elements should have either value of 1.0 if the row in `items1` contains all the elements in the corresponding row of `items2`, or value 0.0 otherwise. The result should look as follows:

```
+---+-----------------+-------------------------+
|id1|           items1|             result_array|
+---+-----------------+-------------------------+
|  0|     [B, C, D, E]|[0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]|
|  1|        [E, A, C]|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]|
|  2|     [F, A, E, B]|[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]|
|  3|        [E, G, A]|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]|
|  4|  [A, C, E, B, D]|[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]|
+---+-----------------+-------------------------+
```

For example, in row 0, the second value is 1.0 because [D] is a subset of [B, C, D, E] and the fourth value is 1.0 because [B, D, C] is a subset of [B, C, D, E]. All other item groups in `df2` are not subsets of [B, C, D, E], thus their indicator values are 0.0.

I've tried to create a list of all item groups in `items2` using collect()  and then apply a udf but my data is too large (over 10 million rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed like this,

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df1 = sql.createDataFrame([
     (0,['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']),
     (1,['E', 'A', 'C']),
     (2,['F', 'A', 'E', 'B']),
     (3,['E', 'G', 'A']),
     (4,['A', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'D'])],
   ['id1','items1'])

df2 = sql.createDataFrame([
     (001,['A', 'C']),
     (002,['D']),
     (003,['E', 'A', 'B']),
     (004,['B', 'D', 'C']),
     (005,['F', 'B']),
     (006,['G', 'E'])],
    ['id2','items2'])
```

Which gives you the dataframes,

```py
+---+---------------+
|id1|         items1|
+---+---------------+
|  0|   [B, C, D, E]|
|  1|      [E, A, C]|
|  2|   [F, A, E, B]|
|  3|      [E, G, A]|
|  4|[A, C, E, B, D]|
+---+---------------+

+---+---------+
|id2|   items2|
+---+---------+
|  1|   [A, C]|
|  2|      [D]|
|  3|[E, A, B]|
|  4|[B, D, C]|
|  5|   [F, B]|
|  6|   [G, E]|
+---+---------+
```

Now, `crossJoin` the two dataframes, which gives you the cartesian product of `df1` with `df2`. Then, `groupby` on `'items1'` and apply a `udf` to get the `'result_array'`.

```py
get_array_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y:[1.0 if set(z) < set(x) else 0.0 for z in y], ArrayType(FloatType()))

df = df1.crossJoin(df2)\
        .groupby(['id1', 'items1']).agg(F.collect_list('items2').alias('items2'))\
        .withColumn('result_array', get_array_udf('items1', 'items2')).drop('items2')

df.show()
```

This gives you the output as,

```py
+---+---------------+------------------------------+                            
|id1|items1         |result_array                  |
+---+---------------+------------------------------+
|1  |[E, A, C]      |[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]|
|0  |[B, C, D, E]   |[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]|
|4  |[A, C, E, B, D]|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]|
|3  |[E, G, A]      |[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]|
|2  |[F, A, E, B]   |[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]|
+---+---------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is an excellent solution. So efficient and simple.