# Pyspark substring of one column based on the length of another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Using Pyspark 2.2

I have a spark DataFrame with multiple columns. I need to input 2 columns to a UDF and return a 3rd column

Input:

```python
+-----+------+
|col_A| col_B|
+-----+------+
|  abc|abcdef|
|  abc|     a|
+-----+------+
```

Both `col_A` and `col_B` are `StringType()`

Desired output:

```python
+-----+------+-------+
|col_A| col_B|new_col|
+-----+------+-------+
|  abc|abcdef|    abc|
|  abc|     a|      a|
+-----+------+-------+
```

I want `new_col` to be a substring of `col_A` with the length of `col_B`.

I tried

```python
udf_substring = F.udf(lambda x: F.substring(x[0],0,F.length(x[1])), StringType())
df.withColumn('new_col', udf_substring([F.col('col_A'),F.col('col_B')])).show()
```

But it gives the `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

Any idea how to do such manipulation?

Answer (score 3):

There are two major things wrong here.

- First, you defined your `udf` to take in one input parameter when it should take 2.
- Secondly, you can't use the API functions within the `udf`. (Calling the `udf` serializes to python so you need to use python syntax and functions.)

Here's a proper `udf` implementation for this problem:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def my_substring(a, b):
    # You should add in your own error checking
    return a[:len(b)]

udf_substring = F.udf(lambda x, y: my_substring(a, b), StringType())
```

And then call it by passing in the two columns as arguments:

```python
df.withColumn('new_col', udf_substring(F.col('col_A'),F.col('col_B')))
```

However, in this case you can do this without a `udf` using the method described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).

```python
df.withColumn(
    'new_col', 
    F.expr("substring(col_A,0,length(col_B))")
)
```

Comment: thanks for this! regarding the second method do we need to add an if else condition for cases when length(col_B) is less than length(col_A) or is it implicitly handled?

Comment: @Wynn the second method will return the full string in `col_A` if the length of `col_B` is less than the length of `col_A`. No `if/else` required.