# Pyspark: Filter data frame if column contains string from another column (SQL LIKE statement)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sql-like

I am trying to filter my pyspark data frame the following way: I have one column which contains `long_text` and one column which contains numbers. If the long text contains the `number` I want to keep the column. 
I am trying to use the SQL `LIKE` statement, but it seems I can't apply it to another column (here `number`)
My code is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col, concat, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import *
PN_in_NC = (df
        .filter(df.long_text.like(concat(lit("%"), df.number, lit("%"))))))
```

I get the following error: 
`Method like([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column]) does not exist`.

I tried multiple things to fix it (such as creating the `'%number%'` string as column before the filter, not using `lit`, `using '%' + number + '%'`) but nothing worked. If `LIKE` can't be applied to another column, is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can use like with `pyspark.sql.functions.expr`. [Using a column value as a parameter to a spark dataframe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `contains` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("hahaha the 3 is good",3),("i dont know about 3",2),("what is 5 doing?",5),\
("ajajaj 123",2),("7 dwarfs",1)], ["long_text","number"]) 
df1.filter(col("long_text").contains(col("number"))).show()
```

The long_text column should contain the number in the number column.

Output:

```
+--------------------+------+
|           long_text|number|
+--------------------+------+
|hahaha the 3 is good|     3|
|    what is 5 doing?|     5|
|          ajajaj 123|     2|
+--------------------+------+
```