# Pyspark, find substring as whole word(s)

Tags: string, pyspark, substring, contains

I would like to see if a string column is contained in another column as a whole word. There are few approaches like using `contains` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866039/pyspark-filter-data-frame-if-column-contains-string-from-another-column-sql-li) or using `array_contains` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566170/how-to-use-pyspark-to-find-whether-a-column-contains-one-or-more-words-in-its-s).

The first approach fails in the following edge case:

```
+---------+-----------------------+
|candidate| sentence              |
+---------+-----------------------+
|  su     |We saw the survivors.  |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

`su` should be found as a separate word and not as a pure substring of the `sentence` column.

The second approach fails when the candidate is a compound word. An example is:

```
+----------------+------------------------+
|candidate       | sentence               |
+----------------+------------------------+
|  Roman emperor | He was a Roman emperor.|
+----------------+------------------------+
```

The second approach fails here because it turns the sentence column to an array of tokens: `[He, was, a, Roman, emperor]` and none of them is equal to `Roman emperor`.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I would think that you would have to do 2 things. First split up the sentence into an array of words and second check if your candidate is in the splitted sentence using e.g `isin()`.

Comment: @k88 that's the second link I mentioned above but it doesn't work because "Roman emperor" are two words.

Comment: Right right. Depending on the complexity of your `candidate`, this ventures into NLP. If so, I would recommend looking into similarity computations, e.g. https://neuml.github.io/txtai/pipeline/text/similarity/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably still has edge cases but I hope you get some ideas.
I would use `regex_extract` to match the candidate against the sentence.

First, I convert the candidate to regex (ie, convert space to \s), then use `regex_extract` with word boundary (\b).

```py
df = (df.withColumn('regex', F.regexp_replace(F.col('candidate'), ' ', '\\\s'))
      .withColumn('match', F.expr(r"regexp_extract(sentence, concat('\\b', regex, '\\b'), 0)")))
```

Result

```
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+
|    candidate|               sentence|         regex|        match|
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+
|           su|  We saw the survivors.|            su|             |
|Roman emperor|He was a Roman emperor.|Roman\semperor|Roman emperor|
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it did work. On a larger set, this is slow, however.

Comment: @pnv that I think you need to optimize on resource side. # of executors, size, CPU etc.