# Convert LongType() to DateType() in pyspark as well as add a date

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` with a column `birth_date` which has values ('123','5345',234345') etc.
I am reading the dataframe first from a csv using

`df = sqlContext.read.csv('s3://path/to/file',header = TRUE)`

Every column is read as StringType(), so I convert the
`birth_date` column to LongType() first (I have to read it as LongType due to some other reasons, I know I can read it as Integer as well, but lets not go into that right now) using the following

`df = df.withColumn('birth_date',df['birth_date'].cast(LongType()))`

Now, how do I make `birth_date` column to DateType as well as add the interger values the column holds, as the number of days with the date "1960-01-01"?

I tried using date_add method [date_add](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_add) using the following command, but I am very new to pyspark and dont understand how column operations behave differently, so I am stuck.

Here is what I tried to do:

`df= df.withColumn('birth_date',date_add("1960-01-01",'birth_date'))`

and I am getting this error

`py4j.Py4JException: Method date_add([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.lang.String]) does not exist`

All my operations are in Databricks pyspark, if it matters at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a column value as a parameter to a spark DataFrame function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function)

Comment: See the linked post for details, but you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.expr` here: `df= df.withColumn('birth_date',expr("date_add('1960-01-01',birth_date)"))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `days` argument of `pyspark.sql.functions.date_add` is expecting an integer, and you are giving it a column name. As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function), you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.expr` to use a column instead (and also a string instead of a column for the `start` argument as you have in your example):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df= df.withColumn('birth_date', expr("date_add('1960-01-01', birth_date)"))
```