# How to filter a python Spark DataFrame by date between two date format columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark 2.1 and i have a dataframe with two columns with date format like this:

```
Column A ,  START_DT       ,  END_DT
1        ,  2016-01-01     ,  2020-02-04
16       ,  2017-02-23     ,  2017-12-24
```

I want to filter for a certain date (for example `2018-12-31`) between the date from `START_DT` and `END_DT` (in the example there, the second row would be filtered).

Both `START_DT` and `END_DT` columns are already in date format, i was looking for a method like the sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM  MYTABLE  WHERE  '2018-12-31' BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using Spark 2.1? That's not necessarily the best Spark release, tbh. Personally I'd raise eyebrows at anything older than 2.4.

Answer (score 10):

If you have a working SQL query, you can always register your DataFrame as a temp table and use `spark.sql()`:

```python
df.createOrReplaceTempView("MYTABLE")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE '2018-12-31' BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt").show()
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|ColumnA|  START_DT|    END_DT|
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|      1|2016-01-01|2020-02-04|
#+-------+----------+----------+
```

Another option is to pass an expression to `where`:

```python
df.where("'2018-12-31' BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt").show()
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|ColumnA|  START_DT|    END_DT|
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|      1|2016-01-01|2020-02-04|
#+-------+----------+----------+
```

One more way is to use [`pyspark.sql.Column.between`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.between.html?highlight=between#pyspark.sql.Column.between) with [`pyspark.sql.functions.lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html), but you'll have to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html) in order to [use a column value as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, expr

test_date = "2018-12-31"
df.where(lit(test_date).between(expr('start_dt'), expr('end_dt'))).show()
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|ColumnA|  START_DT|    END_DT|
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|      1|2016-01-01|2020-02-04|
#+-------+----------+----------+
```

Lastly, you can implement your own version of `between`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.where((col("start_dt") <= lit(test_date)) & (col("end_dt") >= lit(test_date))).show()
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|ColumnA|  START_DT|    END_DT|
#+-------+----------+----------+
#|      1|2016-01-01|2020-02-04|
#+-------+----------+----------+
```