# Split one column based the value of another column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame

```
+----+-------+
|item|   path|
+----+-------+
|   a|  a/b/c|
|   b|  e/b/f|
|   d|e/b/d/h|
|   c|  g/h/c|
+----+-------+
```

I want to find relative path of an of the column *`"item"`*  by locating its value in  column `'path'` and extracting  the path's LHS as shown below

```
+----+-------+--------+
|item|   path|rel_path|
+----+-------+--------+
|   a|  a/b/c|       a|
|   b|  e/b/f|     e/b|
|   d|e/b/d/h|   e/b/d|
|   c|  g/h/c|   g/h/c|
+----+-------+--------+
```

I tried to use  functions *`split((str, pattern)`* or `regexp_extract(str, pattern, idx)` but not sure how to pass the value of column `'item'` into their pattern section . Any idea how that could be done without writing a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) to [pass a column value as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function) to [`regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace). Here you need to concatenate the a negative lookbehind for `item` with `.+` to match everything after, and replace with an empty string.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn(
    "rel_path", 
    expr("regexp_replace(path, concat('(?<=',item,').+'), '')")
).show()
#+----+-------+--------+
#|item|   path|rel_path|
#+----+-------+--------+
#|   a|  a/b/c|       a|
#|   b|  e/b/f|     e/b|
#|   d|e/b/d/h|   e/b/d|
#|   c|  g/h/c|   g/h/c|
#+----+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use get the desired result with combination of `substring` and `instr`

`substring` - Get subset from a column/string

`instr` - Identify the location of particular pattern in search string.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a','a/b/c'),
                            ('b','e/b/f'),
                            ('d','e/b/d/h'),
                            ('c','g/h/c')],'item : string , path : string')

from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, instr, substring

df.withColumn("rel_path",expr("substring(path, 1, (instr(path,item)))")).show()

##+----+-------+--------+
##|item|   path|rel_path|
##+----+-------+--------+
##|   a|  a/b/c|       a|
##|   b|  e/b/f|     e/b|
##|   d|e/b/d/h|   e/b/d|
##|   c|  g/h/c|   g/h/c|
##+----+-------+--------+
```