# How to dynamically slice an Array column in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark 2.4 introduced the new SQL function `slice`, which can be used extract a certain range of elements from an array column.
I want to define that range dynamically per row, based on an Integer column that has the number of elements I want to pick from that column.

However, simply passing the column to the slice function fails, the function appears to expect integers for start and end values. Is there a way of doing this without writing a UDF?

To visualize the problem with an example:
I have a dataframe with an array column `arr` that has in each of the rows an array that looks like `['a', 'b', 'c']`. There also is an `end_idx` column that has elements `3`, `1` and `2`:

```
+---------+-------+
|arr      |end_idx|
+---------+-------+
|[a, b, c]|3      |
|[a, b, c]|1      |
|[a, b, c]|2      |
+---------+-------+
```

I try to create a new column `arr_trimmed` like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l = [(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 1), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ["arr", "end_idx"])

df = df.withColumn("arr_trimmed", F.slice(F.col("arr"), 1, F.col("end_idx")))
```

I expect this code to create the new column with elements `['a', 'b', 'c']`, `['a']`, `['a', 'b']`

Instead I get an error `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a column value as a parameter to a spark DataFrame function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it by passing a SQL expression as follows:

```
df.withColumn("arr_trimmed", F.expr("slice(arr, 1, end_idx)"))
```

Here is the whole working example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l = [(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 1), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 2)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ["arr", "end_idx"])

df.withColumn("arr_trimmed", F.expr("slice(arr, 1, end_idx)")).show(truncate=False)

+---------+-------+-----------+
|arr      |end_idx|arr_trimmed|
+---------+-------+-----------+
|[a, b, c]|3      |[a, b, c]  |
|[a, b, c]|1      |[a]        |
|[a, b, c]|2      |[a, b]     |
+---------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Spark 2.4.0, slice receives columns as arguments. Therefore it can be used as follows:

```
df.withColumn("arr_trimmed", F.slice(arr, F.lit(1), end_idx))
```

David Vrba's example can be rewritten this way:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l = [(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 1), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 2)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ["arr", "end_idx"])

df.withColumn("arr_trimmed", F.slice("arr", F.lit(1), F.col("end_idx"))).show(truncate=False)


+---------+-------+-----------+
|arr      |end_idx|arr_trimmed|
+---------+-------+-----------+
|[a, b, c]|3      |[a, b, c]  |
|[a, b, c]|1      |[a]        |
|[a, b, c]|2      |[a, b]     |
+---------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: This answer is correct and should be accepted as best, with the following clarification - `slice` accepts columns as arguments, as long as both `start` and `length` are given as column expressions.  If for example `start` is given as an integer without `lit()`, as in the original question, I get `py4j.Py4JException: Method slice([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.lang.Integer, class org.apache.spark.sql.Column]) does not exist` (as late as Spark 3.2.1).