# How to remove specific element from a column which is struct type array

Tags: python, arrays, json, pyspark, struct

There is a table which has 10 columns.
One of the column type is struct
And suppose that column name is
xyz.
And xyz contains array of elements.

e.g.,
xyz column contains
[a : value 1, b: value 2, c:value 3...]
Now I want to remove c element from this array.

How do I do it?

This code needs to be done in pyspark/python.

Comment: Please give an example code and in this case structure of your data for others to help.

Comment: You can check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758729/how-to-dynamically-slice-an-array-column-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

You must flatten your struct using something like `df.select('xyz.*')`, then restructure it using [array function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array), [struct function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) as needed.