# Performance Between SQL and withColumn

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I create the following dataframe:

```py
dt = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,5],[2,12],[4,17]]),columns=['a','b'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(dt)
```

I want to create a third column, c, that is the sum of these two columns. I have the following two ways to do so.

The withColumn() method in Spark:

```py
df1 = df.withColumn('c', df.a + df.b)
```

Or using sql:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView('mydf')
df2 = spark.sql('select *, a + b as c from mydf')
```

While both yield the same results, which method is computationally faster?

Also, how does sql compare to a spark user defined function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While both yield the same results, which method is computationally faster?

Look at the execution plans:

```
df1.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(1) Project [a#0L, b#1L, (a#0L + b#1L) AS c#4L]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[a#0L,b#1L]

df2.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(1) Project [a#0L, b#1L, (a#0L + b#1L) AS c#8L]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[a#0L,b#1L]
```

Since these are the same, the two methods are identical.

Generally speaking, there is no computational advantage of using either `withColumn` or `spark-sql` over the other. If the code is written properly, the underlying computations will be identical.

There may be some cases where it's easier to express something using `spark-sql`, for example if you wanted to [use a column value as a parameter to a spark function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).

> Also, how does sql compare to a spark user defined function?

Take a look at this post: [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance?rq=1)