# Check if column is in column array

Tags: arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I have a DataFrame:

```
+-----+---------------+
|thing|         things|
+-----+---------------+
|  foo|[foo, bar, baz]|
|  bar|     [foo, baz]|
|  baz|          [baz]|
+-----+---------------+
```

And I want to check if `thing` is in `things`, i.e. the expected output should be:

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|thing|         things|thing_in_things|
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|  foo|[foo, bar, baz]|           true|
|  bar|     [foo, baz]|          false|
|  baz|          [baz]|           true|
+-----+---------------+---------------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: use [`expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) to [pass `thing` as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function) to [`array_contains`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains). For example: `df.withColumn("thing_in_things", expr("array_contains(things, thing)"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a column value as a parameter to a spark DataFrame function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function)