# Spark: Filter & withColumn using row values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to create a column called `sim_count` for every row in my spark dataframe, whose value is the count of all other rows from the dataframe that match some conditions based on the current row's values. Is it possible to access `row` values while using `when`?

Is something like this possible? I have already implemented this logic using a UDF, but serialization of the dataframe's rdd map is very costly and I am trying to see if there is a faster alternative to find this count value.

**Edit**

`<Row's col_1 val>` refer's to the outer scope row I am calculating the count for, NOT the inner scope row inside the `df.where`. For example, I know this is incorrect syntax, but I'm looking for something like:

```
df.withColumn('sim_count', 
                  f.when(
                    f.col("col_1").isNotNull(),
                    (
                        df.where(
                            f.col("price_list").between(f.col("col1"), f.col("col2"))
                        ).count()
                    )
                  ).otherwise(f.lit(None).cast(LongType()))
                  )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a column value as a parameter to a spark DataFrame function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function)

Comment: Use `expr` for example: `df.where(f.expr("price_list between col1 and col2"))`

Comment: Ah ok will try this! I think I will store `expr` as a string column called `sim_expr` in my dataframe, and do `df.where(f.expr("sim_expr"))` instead

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that would work.

Comment: Thanks, yes just tried and I get `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve `sim_expr`

Comment: @pault I think this is not the row value I am looking for. What I am looking for is the outer scope's row value, not the row value from the `df.where`. Is there a way to use the row value from `f.when` inside `df.where`. The calculation I am doing is a count of similar rows from the entire `df`, **for each row in the dataframe**. Thank you for any and all help

Comment: Can you try to provide a [mcve] with a small sample dataframe and the corresponding desired output?