# How can I query where column exists in another column?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that contains column with page names and another column which contains Json with page list. I would like to check if the page name appears in the page list and filter it if it doesn't.

How can I do it?

df for example:

```
+---------+--------------------------------+
|page name|page_list                       |
+---------+--------------------------------+
|home     |{page_list:['home','something']}|
|about    |{page_list:['something']}       |
+---------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your DataFrame schema is like the following (here the `page_list` column is a string):

```
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- page_name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- page_list: string (nullable = true)
```

You can use [`from_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) to get the `page_list` as an array of strings. Then use [`array_contains`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains) to check if the `page_name` is in this list.

The trick is that you will have to use [`expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) to [pass a column value as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function) to `array_contains`.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, from_json

df.withColumn(
    "flag",
    from_json(
        "page_list", 
        schema=StructType([StructField("page_list", ArrayType(StringType()))])
    )["page_list"]
).withColumn(
    "flag",
    expr("array_contains(flag, page_name)")
).show(truncate=False)
#+---------+----------------------------------+-----+
#|page_name|page_list                         |flag |
#+---------+----------------------------------+-----+
#|home     |{"page_list":["home","something"]}|true |
#|about    |{"page_list":["something"]}       |false|
#+---------+----------------------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do:

```
df2 = (df
      .rdd
      .map(lambda x: (x.page_name, x.page_list, x.page_name in x.page_list['page_list']))
      .toDF(["page_name", "page_list", "flag"])

df2.show()

+---------+--------------------+-----+
|page_name|           page_list| flag|
+---------+--------------------+-----+
|     home|[page_list -> [ho...| true|
|    about|[page_list -> [so...|false|
+---------+--------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column `page_list` is of type string, you could simply use [`contains`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.contains) function like this:

```
quoted_page_name = concat(lit("'"), col("page_name"), lit("'"))    
df.withColumn("flag", col("page_list").contains(quoted_page_name)).show()
```

Gives:

```
+---------+----------------------------------+-----+
|page_name|page_list                         |flag |
+---------+----------------------------------+-----+
|home     |{page_list: ['home', 'something']}|true |
|about    |{page_list: ['something']}        |false|
+---------+----------------------------------+-----+
```

Comment: I would recommend against doing this - it would break if the `page_name` column appeared as a substring anywhere in `page_list`. For example: `{page_list: ['xxxhomeyyy']}` would mistakenly match for `home`

Comment: @pault Yes I agree if it is used as it is. But one can simply quote the page name, i.e  `'home'`...using `concat(lit("'"), col("page_name"), lit("'"))` and it should give correct result.