# Pyspark getting next Sunday based on another date column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a data frame with two date columns - one selected from another data frame and the other is to find the next Sunday after that date. But the issue I'm having is that I'm trying to use `7 - date_format(creation_date, 'u')` to give me the number of days until the next Sunday and add it to the creation date like this:

```py
df = df1.select(to_date(create_time), 
         to_date(date_add(df1.create_time, 7 - date_format(df1.create_time, 'u')))
```

However, this gives me a `Column is not iterable` error  from `date_add`. Is there a solution around it?

Comment: Use `expr`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function

Comment: `f.expr("date_add(to_date(create_time),8-dayofweek(date_time))")`