# Why UDF instead of Function in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning PySpark and come across UDFs. I am not able to understand the diff between Python Functions and UDF in PySpark?

What is the need to use UDF instead of using Functions?

Comment: There are some operations that may not be easily possible using only the Spark API Functions.

Comment: Related: [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297050/5858851)