# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: pyspark UDFs

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

i am  creating a spark UDF inside a class. when i execute the below code i am getting exception.

```
class A(B):
def __init__(self,spark):

    B.__init__(self)

    self.spark = spark



def process(self, df):
    df = df.withColumn("col_sub_entry", self.conditions_title("entry_title"))

def conditions_entry_title(self,x:StringType()):
    if len(x.split(" ") < 3):
        return 0
    else :
        return x
conditions_title = udf(conditions_entry_title, IntegerType())
```

Comment: Can you post the entire class implementation? at least how the udf is implemented? I don't think the way you define `udf` here is a valid syntax inside a class.

Comment: i did, check once

Comment: it worked for me when i use UDF outside class.

Comment: Yes, you must remember pyspark worker nodes do not have class instances created on driver. They only have the basic python methods there.

Comment: You are returning `0` or `x` from `conditions_entry_title`, and `x` can't be an integer type as you specified in the UDF.

Comment: `def conditions_entry_title(self, x:StringType()):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def conditions_entry_title(self, x:StringType()):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: @pisdom. I removed the return x . still facing the issue.

Comment: @prazy import StringType() from pyspark.sql.types import  StringType

Comment: I did. There is a difference between invalid syntax and StringType not defined (when we forget to import StringTye()), right? I get syntax error when I run it in the shell. `def conditions_entry_title(self, x:StringType()):`

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you don't need a `udf` for this- you can use [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when), [`split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split), and [`size`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always [avoid using udfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance/38297050#38297050) when the same operation can be done using the API functions.

This is how I would do it:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, size, split

class A:
  def __init__(self, spark):
      # B.__init__(self)
      self.spark = spark

  def process(self, df):
      df = df.withColumn("col_sub_entry", A.conditions_title("entry_title"))
      return df

  @staticmethod
  def conditions_title(someColumn):
      return when(size(split(col(someColumn), "\s")) < 3, 0).otherwise(1)
```

Or even:

```python
  @staticmethod
  def conditions_title(someColumn):
      return (size(split(col(someColumn), "\s")) >= 3).cast("int")
```

Comment: can we perform "in" conditions in when? example "string" in "string type"

Comment: Yes- you can use [`isin`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin) like: `when(col(someColumn).isin(someIterable), valueIfTrue).otherwise(valueIfFalse)`. You can also do regex matching. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: when i use your split method. it troughs this error : IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: @LUZO that error message does not seem related to any of the code you've provided. It's hard to debug without a [mcve], but I think it would be best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The `conditions_title` you defined in your udf is not consistent; It seems you are trying to define it as a static member of the class but refer to it as an instance method via `self` and also since the `self` in the udf is not used here, you can define it as a static method:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType

class A:
  def __init__(self, spark):
      # B.__init__(self)
      self.spark = spark

  def process(self, df):
      df = df.withColumn("col_sub_entry", A.conditions_title("entry_title"))
      return df

  @staticmethod
  @udf(IntegerType())
  def conditions_title(x: StringType):
      if len(x.split(" ")) < 3:
          return 0
      else :
          return 1
```

Comment: can we define x:StringType()? I am getting the error, invalid syntax.

Comment: @Prazy It works for me to define `x: StringType` without the parenthesis.

Comment: it is throwing me this error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Check `len(x.split(" ") < 3)` in your code. It should be `len(x.split(" ")) < 3`

Comment: it is working but it is taking lot of time to execute the code. even though i am using less  data

Comment: You might want to try the alternative method provided by @pault. `udf` is flexible but not always as efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)