# Pyspark create new data frame with updating few columns from old data frame

Tags: pyspark

I want to create new data frame with updating data from few columns in old data frame in pyspark.

I have below data frame with parquet format which has columns like uid, name, start_dt, addr, extid

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://testdata?src=ggl")
df1 = df.select("uid")
```

I have to create a new data frame in parquet with hashed uid and extid and include the remaining columns also. Please suggest how to do this? I am new :(

Sample input:

```
uid, name, start_dt, addr, extid
1124569-2, abc, 12/02/2018, 343 Beach Dr Newyork NY, 889
```

Sample output:

```
uid, name, start_dt, addr, extid
a8ghshd345698cd, abc, 12/02/2018, 343 Beach Dr Newyork NY, shhj676ssdhghje
```

Here uid and extid are sha256 hashed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired output. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ManojSingh I added them. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a UDF function which call the `hashlib.sha256()` on the column and use the `withColumn` to transform the column.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import hashlib

df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://testdata?src=ggl")

sha256_udf = F.udf(lambda x: hashlib.sha256(str(x).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), T.StringType()) 
df1 = df.withColumn('uid', sha256_udf('uid')).withColumn('extid', sha256_udf('extid'))
df1.show()
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Manoj soluation. Westside's soluation is more specfic but Manoj's soluation is more general. If you like to proceed with learning Spark sooner or late you have to learn what udfs are.
They will help with lot of issues.

Comment: @jonathan sure, `udf`s are flexible and *sometimes* they are the only option but you will get [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance?rq=1) if you can avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

`pyspark` already has builtin function for generating `sha-256` in `pyspark.sql.functions` module.

Create Sample Data

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import sha2
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(
            uid="1124569-2",
            name="abc",
            start_dt="12/02/2018",
            addr="343 Beach Dr Newyork NY",
            extid="889"
        )
     ]
)        
df1.show()
#+--------------------+-----+----+----------+---------+
#|                addr|extid|name|  start_dt|      uid|
#+--------------------+-----+----+----------+---------+
#|343 Beach Dr Newy...|  889| abc|12/02/2018|1124569-2|
#+--------------------+-----+----+----------+---------+
```

Hash selected columns:

```python
df1.select(
    sha2(df1['uid'],256).alias('uid'),
    sha2(df1['extid'],256).alias('extid'),
    'addr',
    'name',
    'start_dt'
).show()
#+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----+----------+
#|                 uid|               extid|                addr|name|  start_dt|
#+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----+----------+
#|4629619cdf1cbeed6...|a829c72c42755e384...|343 Beach Dr Newy...| abc|12/02/2018|
#+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----+----------+
```

We dont have to create `udf`s for that.