# When to use a UDF versus a function in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, azure-databricks

I'm using Spark with Databricks and have the following code:

```
def replaceBlanksWithNulls(column):
    return when(col(column) != "", col(column)).otherwise(None)
```

Both of these next statements work:

```
x = rawSmallDf.withColumn("z", replaceBlanksWithNulls("z"))
```

and using a UDF:

```
replaceBlanksWithNulls_Udf = udf(replaceBlanksWithNulls)
y = rawSmallDf.withColumn("z", replaceBlanksWithNulls_Udf("z"))
```

It is unclear to me from the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) when I should use one over the other and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `UDF` can essentially be any sort of function (there are exceptions, of course) - it is not necessary to use Spark structures such as `when`, `col`, etc. By using an `UDF` the `replaceBlanksWithNulls` function can be written as normal python code:

```
def replaceBlanksWithNulls(s):
    return "" if s != "" else None
```

which can be used on a dataframe column after registering it:

```
replaceBlanksWithNulls_Udf = udf(replaceBlanksWithNulls)
y = rawSmallDf.withColumn("z", replaceBlanksWithNulls_Udf("z"))
```

Note: The default return type of an `UDF` is strings. If another type is required that must be specified when registering it, e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
squared_udf = udf(squared, LongType())
```

---

In this case, the column operation is not complex and there are Spark functions that can acheive the same thing (i.e. `replaceBlanksWithNulls` as in the question:

```
x = rawSmallDf.withColumn("z", when(col("z") != "", col("z")).otherwise(None))
```

This is **always prefered** whenever possible since it allows Spark to optimize the query, see e.g. [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I am finding that writing PySpark code inline (which is more efficient) means I get code reuse. For a simple example, let's say I want to extend the function replaceBlanksWithNulls and also replace NAN or another value with null - Instead of just changing it in one place I'd have to find all of the places I used the inline code. So it may be more efficient, but I am finding it does not lend itself well to reuse... thoughts?

Comment: @Rodney: I would recommend you to continue using methods such as the `replaceBlanksWithNulls` method in your question. It is not an udf since it returns an expression that can be used on one/multiple columns. The performance of this approach is equivalent to "normal" inline code while allowing you to make extensions at a single place.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the difference in the Spark SQL (as mentioned in the document). For example, you can find that if you write:

```
spark.sql("select replaceBlanksWithNulls(column_name) from dataframe")
```

does not work if you didn't register the function `replaceBlanksWithNulls` as a `udf`. In spark sql we need to know the returned type of the function for the exectuion. Hence, we need to register the custom function as a user-defined function (`udf`) to be used in spark sql.

Comment: Thanks - so are you saying in PySpark there is no difference (e.g. performance is the same?

Comment: @Rodney my pleasure. this question is answered https://stackoverflow.com/q/38296609/3768871 as mentioned in the answer of Shaido.