# How is possible that I can use some regular Python functions as UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Consider following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType


def test(val):
   return val + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
  ss = (SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate())

  data = [("James", 3000),
        ("Michael", 4005),
        ("Robert", 4005)]

  schema = (StructType([
    StructField("firstname", StringType(), True),
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)
   ]))

  df = ss.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

  df.withColumn("test", test(col("salary"))).show()
```

How is it possible that it correctly outputs:

```
+---------+------+----+
|firstname|salary|test|
+---------+------+----+
|    James|  3000|3001|
|  Michael|  4005|4006|
|   Robert|  4005|4006|
+---------+------+----+
```

While ***test*** function is NOT defined as `test =udf(test, FloatType())` and it's not registered using `spark.udf.register()`?

Why every tutorial then asks to define and register a UDF? How is it possible that the above just works?

Comment: Are you running you code locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close to a duplicate of [when-to-use-a-udf-versus-a-function-in-pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050825/when-to-use-a-udf-versus-a-function-in-pyspark) but the short answer is your function just returns the col("salary") + 1 (via [Column **add**](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/column.py#L221C5-L221C13)), which gets evaluated as Spark Expressions.

See [here for an explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-__add__-magic-method/) of the magic behind **add**.

Wrapping it in udf forces col("salary") to be evaluated, sent to your udf (which adds one to it) and returned, this will be slower for large amounts of data or calculations than using the Column interface directly.