# replacing characters from phone numbers using pyspark UDF

Tags: python, pyspark

I have written a pyspark code doing following operation but its not working as intended. Can anyone point out my mistake please

```
# Data cleaning function
def clean_data(data):
    rep = data.replace('/','')
    rep = data.replace('-','')
    rep = data.replace('+','')
    rep = data.replace(' ','')
    return  rep

#clean_data_udf_int = udf(lambda z: clean_data(z), StringType())
#con.show(4)
clean_data_udf = udf(clean_data, StringType())
```

```
con = con.withColumn('ph1_f',clean_data_udf('phone1'))
```

Input dataframe is con:

```
id phone phone1
1  098     /90
2  + 91    -90
```

Output i want dataframe is :

```
id phone phone1
1  98     90
2  91     90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning `rep` each time you use `replace`, instead of replacing more things inside `rep` after the first assignment;

```
def clean_data(data):
    rep = data.replace('/','')

    # Now start replacing more things in 'rep' and not the original 'data'
    rep = rep.replace('-','')  
    rep = rep.replace('+','')
    rep = rep.replace(' ','')

    return  rep
```

Otherwise on your last call `rep = data.replace(' ','')` `rep` is the equivalent of the original `data` but with spaces removed. The other replace calls have no effect.

Comment: Thanks, I changed as above, but i still see few instances where "+" is not replaced and still present in records after doing above changes

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you're better off using [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) instead of [using a `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance).

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

def clean_data(data):
    rep = regexp_replace(data, "[\/\-\+ ]", '')
    rep = regexp_replace(rep, "^0", '')
    return rep

df = df.select(
    "id", 
    clean_data(col("phone")).alias("phone"),
    clean_data(col("phone1")).alias("phone1")
)
df.show()
#+---+-----+------+
#| id|phone|phone1|
#+---+-----+------+
#|  1|   98|    90|
#|  2|   91|    90|
#+---+-----+------+
```

Since some of the characters you want to replace have special meaning in regular expressions, they need to be escaped with a `\`.

The first pattern means:

- `[\/\-\+ ]`: Match a single character present in `["/", "-", "+", " "]`

The second replace pattern means:

- `^0`: Replace a 0 starting at the beginning of the string. You can change this to `^0+` if you expect there to be multiple leading `0`s.