# pyspark udf clean html tags getting typeerror

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark, and I'm having trouble converting python functions to pyspark udf.

I have a df as below

```
+--------------------+
|             summary|
+--------------------+
|<p>test test </p>   |
|<a>test test </a>   |
|<p>test test </p>   |
+--------------------+
```

I wanted to clean up the html tags in `summary`. I have created a udf as below

```
import re
clean_html = udf(lambda raw: re.sub(re.compile('<.*?>'), '', raw))
df.withColumn('clean', clean_html(df.summary))
```

but getting the following error when running:
`TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column`

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you give the result of  `print(df.schema)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the udf function and use directly `regexp_replace`

```py
# First import regexp_replace
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

# Creates the dataframe 
# [...]

# Pass the column, regex and replacement value
df = df.withColumn('clean', regexp_replace(df.summary, r'<.*?>', ''))

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------------+----------+
|          summary|     clean|
+-----------------+----------+
|<p>test test </p>|test test |
|<a>test test </a>|test test |
+-----------------+----------+
```

Before create an `UDF`, always check if has a native function provided from Spark to solve your demand.

Python `UDF` has an impact performance against JVM, this is mentioned in their book `Spark The Definitive Guide` and there's a discuss here that you can see too: [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the column to the UDF in a wrong way!
Try this:

```
import re
clean_html = udf(lambda raw: re.sub(re.compile('<.*?>'), '', raw))
df.withColumn('clean', clean_html("summary"))
```

or this:

```
import re
clean_html = udf(lambda raw: re.sub(re.compile('<.*?>'), '', raw))
df.withColumn('clean', clean_html(col("summary")))
```

and the result:

```
+-----------------+----------+
|          summary|     clean|
+-----------------+----------+
|<p>test test </p>|test test |
|<a>test test </a>|test test |
+-----------------+----------+
```