# Flattening a 2 level nested list using list comprehension only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list

```
In [13]:  nested_list=[0,25,[0,2,3,4],[1,1,-1,-1]]
```

and I'd like to flatten it as follows:

```
[0,25,0,2,3,4,1,1,-1,-1]
```

using the following list comprehension

```
[y for y in x if isinstance(x,list) else x for x in nested_list]
```

But I'm getting this error

```
 In [16]: [y for y in x if isinstance(x,list) else x for x in nested_list]
 File "<ipython-input-16-e49b6b9924a1>", line 1
[y for y in x if isinstance(x,list) else x for x in nested_list]
                                       ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know there are multiple solutions not using a list comprehension but recursion.
However, I'd like to use a list comprehension.
Can someone advice as to the correct syntax ?

Comment: Nope, its different

Comment: Add parentheses where they belong. It wouldn't help though

Comment: @MadPhysicist your comment inspired me- you can do it with parentheses if you switch the order a bit: `[y for x in nested_list for y in (x if isinstance(x,list) else [x])]`

Comment: @pault. That's a good solution if you only ever have 0 or 1 levels of nesting. You should post an answer

Answer (score 3):

One way using a list comprehension:

```
[y for z in [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in nested_list] for y in z]
#[0, 25, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

**Update**

Even simpler:

```
[y for x in nested_list for y in (x if isinstance(x,list) else [x])]
#[0, 25, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: you could turn the inner list comp into a generator which may improve performance, depending on how big your `nested_list` is

Comment: It's small, and I'd like to use it within a Pyspark udf.

Comment: If it's for `pyspark`, version 2.4 has a [`flatten`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten) function which will be [better than using a `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance). In any case, you don't need a list comprehension for a `udf`, you can use other methods (like the easier to read simple loop).

Comment: It's for a vector type field, and using flatten is giving me this error
`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve ;flatten(features) due to data type mismatch:`

Comment: Oh if it's `VectorUDT` you will have to use `udf`.

Answer (score 2):

Limited to a list `x` composed of `list` and `int`, it can be done via

```
x = [0,25,[0,2,3,4],[1,1,-1,-1]]
res = []
for i in x:
    if type(i) == int:
        res.append(i)
    else:
        res += i 
print(res)
```

Output

```
[0, 25, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

---

Write above in one line of code.

```
x = [0,25,[0,2,3,4],[1,1,-1,-1]]
sum([[i] if type(i) == int else i for i in x],[])
```

Comment: Can I do it via list comprehension though ?

Comment: He/She is asking to do it with a comprehension

Comment: @femibyte check the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension only, variant with `type()` instead of `isinstance`:

```
nested_list=[0,25,[0,2,3,4],[1,1,-1,-1]]

[i for sublist in [[x] if type(x) == int else x for x in nested_list] for i in sublist]
```