# Does spark GROUPED_MAP udf on a data frame run parallelly?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to apply a PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP function which takes a data frame as input and yields a data frame as an output. When I do sdf.groupby(key).apply(pandas_udf) does it apply the function parallelly to multiple groups based on available resources or sequentially one group after the other?
I haven't changed any default settings of spark. What other alternatives can I employ if I want to execute udf on groups parallelly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes UDFs are executed parallel but the execution is not as optimized as spark native functions.

More info here:
[Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)