# Apply java funciton URLDecoder.decode to whole column in Spark 3

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe column containing url encoded string such as:

I would like to do something like that:

```
someDF.withColumn('newcol', URLDecoder.decode( col("mystring"), "utf-8" ))
someDF.show()
|         mystring         |         newcol      |
--------------------------------------------------
| ThisIs%201rstString      | ThisIs 1rstString   |        
| This%20is%3Ethisone      | This is>thisone     |
| and%20so%20one           | and so one          |
```

How should I do such thing I guess map function is around the corner but can't firgure out  how to us it.

Note: this is a sample and it is not an option to create multiple replace statement as there is many other encoded characters and list may vary, I'd like to use a simple reliable method to do so.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the SparkSQL builtin function [reflect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#reflect):

> reflect(class, method[, arg1[, arg2 ..]]) - Calls a method with reflection.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(e,) for e in ["ThisIs%201rstString", "This%20is%3Ethisone", "and%20so%20one"]], ["mystring"])

df.selectExpr("*", "reflect('java.net.URLDecoder','decode', mystring, 'utf-8') as newcol").show()

+-------------------+-----------------+
|           mystring|           newcol|
+-------------------+-----------------+
|ThisIs%201rstString|ThisIs 1rstString|
|This%20is%3Ethisone|  This is>thisone|
|     and%20so%20one|       and so one|
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

**Note:** the above is Python code, you should be able to do the same with Scala.

Comment: is there a major difference with defining an UDF ?

Comment: in short words, the builtin functions are simple and less overhead, UDF is not vectorized and usually less performant. this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609 lists some major points compared to PySpark UDF, but also include Scala/Java.

Comment: OK, interesting, I never use `pyspark` for several reason, one because it's `python`, two because I know that there's performance hit with `pyspark` though has been reduce in SPARK 3, in that case I would rather use pure scala but `reflect` function seems to only be available in SQL.

Comment: yeah, it's not directly available with pyspark (not sure about Scala/Java), you can access it using `expr("reflect(......)")` though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [UDF](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs.html) that performs the work

```scala
import java.net.URLDecoder
def decode(in:String) =  URLDecoder.decode(in, "utf-8")
val decode_udf = udf(decode(_))
df.withColumn("newcol", decode_udf('mystring)).show()
```

prints the expected result.

Comment: Nice it does work but add a huge performance impact, I will try to look for something a bit less heavy.