# how to merge the multiple columns in single columns using UDF and remove the 0 value row from the column in pyspark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

```
df_Description3 = df_Description1.fillna(value="0",subset=["DES","INV","MKT","SHO"])
lst_Cols= ["DES","INV","MKT","SHO"]
def Merge(c1,c2,c3,c4):
    if "DES"!="0":
        return c1
    elif "INV"!='0':
        return c2
    elif "MKT"!="0":
        return c3
    elif "SHO"!="0":
        return c4
    return c1,c2,c3,c4

myudf = F.udf(Merge,StringType())

df_Description3 = df_Description3.withColumn("Descriptions",myudf("DES","INV","MKT","SHO")).show()
```

Comment: what's the intent of the function `merge()`? can you share your target dataframe?

Comment: share ur df_Description1 and target dataframe would be better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using UDFs is not recommended as it can impact performance (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)). So here is a solution using spark functions. Note that [concat_ws()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html) will handle nulls during the merging of columns so you don't have to do the extra step of filling with `0` and then removing it. At the end if all 4 columns are null then you can drop the row by checking if it is empty.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_Description3 = df_Description3.withColumn("Descriptions", F.concat_ws(" ", "DES", "INV", "MKT", "SHO"))
df_Description3 = df_Description3.filter(F.col("Descriptions") != "")
df_Description3.show()
```