# Nested withColumn and otherwise Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this code:

```
dfSpark = dfSpark\
    .withColumn('colA', when(col('colA') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colB', when(col('colB') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colC', when(col('colC') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colD', when(col('colD') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colE', when(col('colE') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colF', when(col('colF') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colG', when(col('colG') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colH', when(col('colH') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colI', when(col('colI') == True, 'S').otherwise('N')) \
    .withColumn('colJ', when(col('colJ') == True, 'S').otherwise('N'))
```

Is there any other way that could be more efficient and not redundant? Something like a lambda in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use select with list comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

update_cols = ["colA", "colB", "colC", "colD", "colE", "colF", "colG", "colH", "colI", "colJ"]

dfSpark = dfSpark.select(
    *[F.col(c) for c in df.columns if c not in update_cols],
    *[F.when(F.col(c), "S").otherwise("N") for c in update_cols]
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use UDF (user defined functions):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def my_udf(col):
  if col == True:
    return "S"
  else:
    return "N"
```

and call it as:

```
dfSpark = dfSpark \
    .withColumn('colA', my_udf(col('colA')) \
    .withColumn('colB', my_udf(col('colB'))
```

But remember, **UDFs involve repeated serialization, deserialization and data movement between Python interpreter and JVM, and may be very slow for huge datasets. The vectorised form (as you've coded) is more efficient**.

There are vectorised UDFs, as well. Please check https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

Performance: [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)