# performance about withColumn many times or use udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a curious question about dataframe, I saw this code

```
 df.
  withColumn("emailF", trim($"email")).
  withColumn("emailF", regexp_replace($"emailF", " +", "")).
  withColumn("emailF", lower($"emailF"))
```

But I said that I prefer to use udf function to apply all rules to format email, a udf like this:

```
val customUdf = udf((txt:String) => {
txt.toLower.trim.replaceAll(" +","")
//another logic
})
```

my question is:
What is better?
use multiple `withColumn` in the same column to apply multiple functions or use a one function and apply all rules inside.

thanks for your answers and suggestions.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to test by yourself.

Comment: I would bet it's very similar though as I guess Spark optimisations "merge" the 3 `withColumn`.

Comment: Some helpful links in this context: [Spark functions vs UDF performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance), [Introducing Pandas UDF for PySpark](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html), [Working with UDFs in Apache Spark](https://blog.cloudera.com/working-with-udfs-in-apache-spark/)