# (PySpark) Create a new array column containing the binary comparison results of a list column and a static list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**The Scenario**

I have a dataframe containing the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, StructType, StructField
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

a = [1,2,3]
b = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': a,
    'list1': b,
})

df=spark.createDataFrame(df) 
df.printSchema()
df.show()

+---+---------+
| id|    list1|
+---+---------+
|  1|[a, b, c]|
|  2|[d, e, f]|
|  3|[g, h, i]|
+---+---------+
```

I also have a static list containing the following values

```
 list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

**What I want to do**

I want to compare each value of `list2` to each value of `list1` in my data, and build an array of 0/1 values with 1 indicating that the value of `list2` was or was not present in `list1`.

The resulting output should look like this:

```
+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
| id|    list1  |   result                    |
+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
|  1| [a, b, c] | [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
|  2| [d, e, f] | [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] |
|  3| [g, h, i] | [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] |
+---+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

I need the results in this format because I am eventually going to be multiplying the `result` arrays by a scaling factor.

**My attempt**

```
# Insert the new_list into the dataframe
df = df.withColumn("list2", F.array([F.lit(x) for x in new_list]))

# Get the result arrays
differencer = F.udf(lambda list1, list2: F.array([1 if x in list1 else 0 for x in list2]), ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df = df.withColumn('result', differencer('list1', 'list2'))

df.show()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o151.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 287) (ip-10-0-0-142.ec2.internal executor 8): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to run command: /usr/bin/virtualenv -p python3 --system-site-packages virtualenv_application_1665327460183_0007_0
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.VirtualEnvFactory.execCommand(VirtualEnvFactory.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.VirtualEnvFactory.setupVirtualEnv(VirtualEnvFactory.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.<init>(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.$anonfun$createPythonWorker$1(SparkEnv.scala:125)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(EvalPythonExec.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1474)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I've tried dozens of iterations and approaches, but literally everything I do results in the above error.

How can I get this to work? Ideally without having to insert `list2` into the dataframe prior to running the comparison.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to add `list2` as extra column to the dataframe and then use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) to check for each element of the newly added column if it is [part of the array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html) in column `list1`.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("result", F.array(*map(F.lit, list2))) \
    .withColumn("result", F.transform("result", lambda v: F.array_contains(F.col("list1"), v).cast("int"))) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+---------------------------+
|id |list1    |result                     |
+---+---------+---------------------------+
|1  |[a, b, c]|[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|2  |[d, e, f]|[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]|
|3  |[g, h, i]|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]|
+---+---------+---------------------------+
```

Using the built-in function `transform` is faster than an udf as it avoids the [overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297050/2129801) that comes with udfs.