# Finding the value of a column based on other 2 columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have specific problem, where I want to retrieve the value of `bu_id` field from `id` and `matched_ id`.

When there is some value in `matched_id` column, `bu_id` should be same as the `id` for that particular `id` and `id`s of corresponding `matched_id`.

When `matched_id` is blank, `bu_id` should be same as `id`.

`input`

```
+---+------------+
|id |matched_id  |
+---+------------+
|0  |7,8         |
|1  |            |
|2  |4           |
|3  |5,9         |
|4  |2           |
|5  |3,9         |
|6  |            |
|7  |0,8         |
|8  |0,7         |
|9  |3,5         |
```

`output`

```
+---+------------+-----+
|id |matched_id  |bu_id|
+---+------------+-----+
|0  |7,8         |0    |
|1  |            |1    |
|2  |4           |2    |
|3  |5,9         |3    |
|4  |2           |2    |
|5  |3,9         |3    |
|6  |            |6    |
|7  |0,8         |0    |
|8  |0,7         |0    |
|9  |3,5         |3    |
```

Can anyone help me how to approach this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify,
If the `matched_id` column is null, then `bu_id` should be the same as `id`.
If the `matched_id` column is **not** null, we should consider the values listed in both the `id` and `matched_id` columns and `bu_id` should be the minimum of those values.
Is that correct?

Comment: what is the type of each column in your input df? can you include the output from `df.schema` in your question? thanks!

Comment: All columns are `stringType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should try to use functions exclusively from the [pyspark.sql.functions module](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) because these are optimized for pyspark dataframes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance)), whereas udfs are not and should be avoided when possible.

To achieve the desired output pyspark dataframe, we can [concatenate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat.html) both `"id"` and `"matched_id"` columns together, convert the string that into a list of strings using [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html), cast the result as an array of integers, and take the [minimum of the array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_min.html) – and we can get away with not having to worry about the blank strings because they get converted into `null`, and `F.array_min` drops nulls from consideration. This can be done with the following line of code (and while it is a little hard to read, it gets the job done):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("0", "7,8"),
        ("1", ""),
        ("2", "4"),
        ("3", "5,9"),
        ("4", "2"),
        ("5", "3,9"),
        ("6", ""),
        ("7", "0,8"),
        ("8", "0,7"),
        ("9", "3,5"),
    ],
    ["id", "matched_id"]
)

df.withColumn(
    "bu_id", 
    F.array_min(F.split(F.concat(F.col("id"),F.lit(","),F.col("matched_id")),",").cast("array<int>"))
).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|matched_id|bu_id|
+---+----------+-----+
|  0|       7,8|    0|
|  1|          |    1|
|  2|         4|    2|
|  3|       5,9|    3|
|  4|         2|    2|
|  5|       3,9|    3|
|  6|          |    6|
|  7|       0,8|    0|
|  8|       0,7|    0|
|  9|       3,5|    3|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Update: in the case of non-numeric strings in columns "id" and "matched_id", we can no longer cast to an array of integers, so we can instead use pyspark functions `F.when` and `.otherwise` (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.when.html)) to set our new column to the `"id"` column when `"matched_id"` is an empty string `""`, and apply our other longer nested function when `"matched_id"` is non-empty.

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("0", "7,8"),
        ("1", ""),
        ("2", "4"),
        ("3", "5,9"),
        ("4", "2"),
        ("5", "3,9"),
        ("6", ""),
        ("7", "0,8"),
        ("8", "0,7"),
        ("9", "3,5"),
        ("x", ""),
        ("x", "y,z")
    ],
    ["id", "matched_id"]
)

df2.withColumn(
    "bu_id", 
    F.when(F.col("matched_id") != "", F.array_min(F.split(F.concat(F.col("id"),F.lit(","),F.col("matched_id")),","))).otherwise(
        F.col("id")
    )
).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|matched_id|bu_id|
+---+----------+-----+
|  0|       7,8|    0|
|  1|          |    1|
|  2|         4|    2|
|  3|       5,9|    3|
|  4|         2|    2|
|  5|       3,9|    3|
|  6|          |    6|
|  7|       0,8|    0|
|  8|       0,7|    0|
|  9|       3,5|    3|
|  x|          |    x|
|  x|       y,z|    x|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks @Derek, the solution is correct. One addendum to it, if the `id` or `matched_id` column has proper `string` values like x, y etc. Would the `array_min` work or we need to think of some other solution.

Comment: @SDS i've updated the solution for a situation where you might have non-numeric strings in `id` or `matched_id`. we'll have to avoid trying to cast to an array of integers because that will fail for situations where matched_id might look like `"x","y"`, and we'll instead use `F.when` and `.otherwise` which will allow us to apply one function when matched_id is an empty string `""`, and apply a different function when matched_id has a non-empty string

Comment: and `array_min` still works because strings can be compared. `"x"` is less than `"y"`, for example. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I assumed that the logic you are looking to implement is,

- If the `matched_id` column is null, then `bu_id` should be the same as `id`.
- If the `matched_id` column is not null, we should consider the values listed in both the `id` and `matched_id` columns and `bu_id` should be the minimum of those values.

**The Set-Up**

```
# imports to include
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
```

```
# making your dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('0','7,8'),
     ('1',''),
     ('2','4'),
     ('3','5,9'),
     ('4','2'),
     ('5','3,9'),
     ('6',''),
     ('7','0,8'),
     ('8','0,7'),
     ('9','3,5'),
    ],
    ['id', 'matched_id'])
print(df.schema.fields)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

In this df, both the `id` and `matched_id` columns are StringType data types. The code that follows builds-off this assumption. You can check the column types in your df by running `print(df.schema.fields)`

| id | matched_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 7,8 |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5,9 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3,9 |
| 6 |  |
| 7 | 0,8 |
| 8 | 0,7 |
| 9 | 3,5 |

**The Logic**

To implement the logic for bu_id, we created a function called `bu_calculation` that defines the logic. Then we wrap the function in pyspark sql UDF. The `bu_id` column is then created by inputing the columns we need to evaluate (the `id` and `matched_id` columns) into the UDF

```
# create custom function with the logic for bu_id
def bu_calculation(id_col, matched_id_col):
    id_int = int(id_col)
    
    # turn the string in the matched_id column into a list and remove empty values from the list
    matched_id_list = list(filter(None, matched_id_col.split(",")))
    
    if len(matched_id_list) > 0:
        # if matched_id column has values, convert strings to ints
        all_ids = [int(x) for x in matched_id_list]
        
        # join id column values with matched_id column values
        all_ids.append(id_int)
        
        # return minimum value
        return min(all_ids)
    
    else:
        # if matched_id column is empty return the id column value
        return id_int

# apply custom bu_calculation function to pyspark sql udf
# the use of IntegerType() here enforces that the bu_calculation function has to return an int
bu_udf = F.udf(bu_calculation, IntegerType())

# make a new column called bu_id using the pyspark sql udf we created called bu_udf
df = df.withColumn('bu_id', bu_udf('id', 'matched_id'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

| id | matched_id | bu_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7,8 | 0 |
| 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 5,9 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3,9 | 3 |
| 6 |  | 6 |
| 7 | 0,8 | 0 |
| 8 | 0,7 | 0 |
| 9 | 3,5 | 3 |

More about the pyspark sql udf function here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html

Comment: while this solution works, i feel like it's important to point out that udfs are not optimized for pyspark dataframes. sometimes we have to resort to udfs because the transformation we want to make to a pyspark dataframe is too complicated to be done with any of the functions from `pyspark.sql.functions`, but i think it's possible to solve this problem without udfs. but this is a good effort, has the advantage of being a bit more readable, and could be repurposed for a similar, but more complicated problem!

Comment: thanks a lot @smurphy for the solution.. I have solution in `udf` as well. However, I wanted something in pyspark