# Dot product calculation for angle between vectors in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark

I am trying to calculate the angle between two vectors using PySpark in Databricks. This is a fairly trivial task in Python, but I can't seem to create an efficient method in Pyspark with the main blocking point being the calculation of the dot product.

As I have been unable to calculate the dot product at all in Pyspark, I have chosen to implement my method in a UDF using numpy functions, but the outcome is not as fast as I would have liked. I'd appreciate any input on how to achieve this using more of PySpark itself, rather than relying on numpy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@udf("float")
def calculateAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    a = np.array([x1,y1])
    b = np.array([x2,y2])
    c = np.array([x3,y3])

    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b

    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    returnValue = np.degrees(np.arccos(cosine_angle))
    return returnValue.item()

data = {'x1':1.23, 'y1':3.23, 'x2':1.25, 'y2':3.2, 'x3':1.3, 'y3':2.8,}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0]) 
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df=df.withColumn("angle", calculateAngle('x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2', 'x3', 'y3'))
df=df.toPandas()
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python UDFs are slow: [Spark functions vs UDF performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance). The angle computation between 2-dim vectors can be expressed in Spark:

```
from pyspark.sql import Column
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = {'a1': 0, 'a2': 1, 'b1': 0, 'b2': 0, 'c1': 1, 'c2': 1}
_vals = [tuple(v for k, v in data.items())]
_schema = [k for k, v in data.items()]
df = spark.createDataFrame(_vals, _schema)

ba1 = F.col('a1') - F.col('b1')
ba2 = F.col('a2') - F.col('b2')
bc1 = F.col('c1') - F.col('b1')
bc2 = F.col('c2') - F.col('b2')
dot_product = ba1 * bc1 + ba2 * bc2

ba_length = F.sqrt((ba1 ** 2) + (ba2 ** 2))
bc_length = F.sqrt((bc1 ** 2) + (bc2 ** 2))

angle = F.acos(dot_product / (ba_length * bc_length))

df = df.withColumns({
    'angle_radians': angle,
    'angle_degrees': F.degrees(angle),
})
df.show()

# +---+---+---+---+---+---+------------------+-----------------+
# | a1| a2| b1| b2| c1| c2|     angle_radians|    angle_degrees|
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+------------------+-----------------+
# |  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|  1|0.7853981633974484|45.00000000000001|
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+------------------+-----------------+
```