Passing dataframe column as an argument to a function inpyspark
I'm new to pyspark and trying to explore some new methods of implementation. I'm trying to pass a derived column in a dataframe as an argument to a function which queries and returns a value
def getValue(col):
   cfg = spark.sql("select value from config_table where key='"+str(col)+"'")
   value = cfg.collect()[0][0]
   return value

main():
   df_output = df.withColumn('derived',getValue(col('col_to_fetch_the_value')))

The above code results in syntax error.
Thanks in advance
Trying the below code works for me which cannot be used as the column value might change and cannot be hardcoded
def getValue(col):
   cfg = spark.sql("select value from config_table where key='"+str(col)+"'")
   value = cfg.collect()[0][0]
   return value

main():
   df_output = df.withColumn('derived',getValue('key'))


Where is 'key' (aka 'col_to_fetch_the_value') coming from - Does the df have a column that defines the 'key' you are looking up? Or is this input from some other function/operator?

@smurphy, 'key' does exists in the column 'col_to_fetch_the_value'. the question is why am i not able to pass a dataframe column as an argument to a function

Check out the 'Example left join' answer below, that should solve your issue. This site also has some images to accompany the join explanations that might help - https://iomete.com/resources/reference/pyspark/pyspark-join#left-outer-join

Column values can be passed to a function is using PySpark UDF (link with examples is shared in the answer below). However join is a native PySpark function. Here is some info explaining why native PySpark functions are preferred to using PySpark UDFs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance

This seems like an opportunity to use joins.
Example left join
If your input df defines the look-up key, you could use a left join to apply the derived value to the rows where that look-up key is defined
config_df = spark.sql("SELECT key, value from config_table")

df_output = df.join(config_df, df.col_to_fetch_the_value=config_df.key "left").withColumnRenamed("value", "derived")

getValue() Function
From what I can see so far, there is not a clear case for using the getValue function over using a join.
If you have a case where you must use the getValue function, use the PySpark UDF function to pass the getValue function as your column definition: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html
